# react-router is not filling params

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using react router on a project and when I'm using the `Link` tag I'm not getting `this.props.params` properly filled when reading it on the new Page.

```
<Link to='/users/login/' params={{firstParam: 'firstParam'}} query={{firstParam: 'firstParam'}}>link</Link>
```

Anyone knows why it could be?

EDIT:
I've also tried doing it this way

```
this.refs.linkToLogin.context.router.transitionTo('/users/login', {firstParam: 'firstParam'});
```

EDIT2:
The route is defined this way

```
<Route name="users">
  ...
  <Route name="users-login" path="/users/login" handler={UserPage} />
  ...
</Route>
```

Comment: which version of react router? doesn't look like Link takes a params prop https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#link

Comment: 0.13.3 For which version is that documentation?

Comment: If it cannot be done this way. Do you know how can I pass objects to the new page?

Comment: is your RouteHandler setup to accept the first and second argument from the callback in `Router.run`? https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/0.13.x/docs/guides/overview.md#dynamic-segments

can you post your routes file?

Comment: I've edited so you can see how I've defined it

Comment: @JavierManzano the docs I linked to are from master (1.0), sorry I haven't worked with versions below that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your link is set up correctly, I expect its an issue with your route handler. it must be configured to accept the `state` argument from the callback function. your routes file should look like this:

```
Router.run(routes, function(Handler, state){
  React.render(<Handler {...state} />, document.querySelector('#foo')
})
```

the important thing to note here is the `state` argument in the callback function getting passed to the `Handler` component

additionally, your route needs to be configured to accept a dynamic param. The `#props.query` should go through correctly, but unless a dynamic segment of the url is defined, the `params` likely wont show up

```
<Route name='...' path='/users/:firstParam/login' handler={UserPage} />
```